# Search term in Google Drive to filter for Fusion Tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

It used to be possible to filter for fusion tables using a `type:` query.  But now there appears to be no string to put after `type:` in the drive.google.com search field to filter out the fusion tables.

Does anyone know of an answer or workaround for this?

We do use the Fusion table API, and I know how to list tables that way.  But if the tables are effectively hidden in the human UI, it becomes very hard to find and share them by hand rather than programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can add app:"Google Fusion Tables" to the Drive search bar. Unfortunately this was removed from the UI, but the keyword still works.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) search box, try the following:

```
type:table
```